# How to pass blank parameters to a script called in crontab (Linux)

Tags: linux, cron, arguments

I am trying to pass a blank parameter using double quotes, `""`, but it just gets ignored. All parameters after the blank parameter end up in the wrong position in the called script.

My [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview) entry looks like:

```
* * * * * myscript.sh A B "" C D
```

Parameters A and B end up in the correct position in *myscript.sh*, but D and E end up in parameter positions 3 and 4 in *myscript.sh* (instead of positions 4 and 5).

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're doing it correctly. The problem is probably in the script.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you type that command by hand in the shell?

Comment: Yes it does work correctly if i type the command from the shell. Thanks

Comment: I just tested with a script that contains `echo "$4" > myscript.out`. It correctly wrote `C` to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest (without having tested it) the following:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env bash -c 'myscript.sh A B "" C D'
```

or alternatively just

```
* * * * * bash -c 'myscript.sh A B "" C D'
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. `cron` executes the command by doing `bash -c`. The only change it makes is to replace `%` with newline.

Comment: YES!! that did the trick. Thanks patate. To be clear I did all you said except the "bash -c" part

Comment: Actually, now it's passing two double quotes instead of space. I thought your answer worked but now it looks like not.

Comment: In your initial question you said _"I am trying to pass a blank parameter"_, so just replacing "" with " " should do the trick in order to get your single space instead of the blank parameter.

Comment: I did my tests with a bash script, meaning that `myscript.sh` would have the shebang `#!/bin/bash`. Maybe you are using a different interpretator for your script and that is why `""` and `" "` don't get resolved as expected.